# According to Catholic Social Doctrine what duties do Catholics have towards sex offenders on supervisory release?

Tags: catholicism, civil-government

If a government authority decides to place two child sex offenders on Supervisory Release in a vacant house in the immediate proximity of ones family, should that placement be fought or is it the duty of Catholics to welcome the imprisoned and the sinner?

Given that the stipulation of their release is that they have no contact with neighbors with children (and especially their children) is it even a charitable thing to have neighbors such as these?

Comment: This question isn't a complaint, I've already made several complaints.  Our town board has the ability to relocate them and since we're both Catholics, I was interested in what duties he might have as a Catholic civil leader and what duties I might have as a father.

Comment: Do not know about the Catholic Social Doctrine in this case,but I can assure you that Catholics do volunteer to aide sex offenders into the community. Having been involved in such cases, I can honestly say that it is a very complicated process. In our support circle, we are obliged by law to tell the police of all possible breaches made by a particular offender. Most (95+%) sex offenders who accept our program never go back to prison. The one case that I am familiar with that did not work was with a woman sex offender!!! I am not talking about prostitution either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the last line makes it “x is a sin “ against charity. Opinions will vary even in Catholic Social teachings because the virtue of prudence is involved.

Comment: @ken I think variance in Catholic Social teaching is OK here. My opinion on this site is that it has always been OK (even encouraged) to have contradictory answers as long as there is something objective to hold them to.

Comment: In fact, I'd heartily encourage a contradictory answer to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/71598/is-the-theology-of-the-body-in-line-with-traditional-thomistic-teaching-on-marri)